Sport movie about a male rings gymnast
I am searching for years.. I am looking for a movie about a guy who is making a lot of sport with wooden rings like these. 

Plot: I think the movie is in the 90s. The main character needs motivation to do his sport. His class mates are better then him. After a while he is seeing an old man on a roof of a gas station. A few seconds later the old man is in the gas station and is repairing a car.
I don't know why but I think the old man is just a ghost or only visible to the sport guy.
At the end the sport guy is going to the Olympics and wins a gold medal.
Does anybody know the name of the movie?

Peaceful Warrior from 2006 with Nick Nolte.

Dan Millman has it all: good grades, a shot at the Olympic team on the rings and girls lining up for the handsome Berkely college athlete all teams mates look up to with envy. Only one man shakes his confidence, an anonymous night gas station attendant, who like Socrates, keeps questioning every assumption in his life. Then a traffic crash shatters Dan's legs, and his bright future. Now Socrates's life coaching is to make or break Dan's revised ambition. 

Based on former gymnast Dan Millman's semi-autobiographical book. Here's the trailer, where you can briefly see Dan being perplexed by the old man's roof trick at the gas station:




thank you so much you are my hero. I looked for this movie like for 4 years !
